# Mercurial / SCM Manager : How to disable clone capability even if user has read-only permission on a repo?

Tags: mercurial

On Mercurial / SCM Manager, we want to enforce following policy:
User with read-only permission on a repo shall be able to browse the repo in web browser - bu tshall not be able to clone the repo on local PC.

Repo Clone/download on local PC shall be allowed only if user/AD group that he/she is part of has READ-WRITE permission on the repo.

Thanks in advance,
Manish

Comment: Reading implies the capability to clone a repo. When I can read a thing, I can save it locally. Write permission implies that I can modify it. Cloning is not a task which changes a repo a single bit.
Your question is probably much less a mercurial question than one concerning SCM manager which may or may not allow such config. Or maybe some config on your web server can help with it. Mercurial cannot.